# Vaadin 8 (withouth Spring Boot/Security) and Keycloak not working

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, keycloak, vaadin8

I have a 'legacy' application build with Vaadin 8 that I need to secure with Keycloak.
Unfortunately, the redirect to Keycloak is not even triggered.

As a test, I created a Spring Boot application and tried to secure it with Keycloak without any problems, but it fails to work with Vaadin 8.

My configuration files for the Spring Boot application are;

application.properties

```
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.resource=test-app
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=Patient
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[1]=Admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=boeken
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/books

keycloak.securityConstraints[1].authRoles[0]=Admin
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].name=backend
keycloak.securityConstraints[1].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/manager

server.port=8090
```

KeycloakConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

Just by adding this, the Keycoal-redirect is triggered and I can log in. Easy.

What should I change/add when i'm trying to secure the Vaadin 8 application?
It's not a Spring/Spring boot-application (not started by SpringApplication.run()), I don't think it's mandatory to have a Spring/Spring boot app in order to secure it with Keycloak (correct me if i'm wrong). 
The problem seems to be that the application.properties file is ignored (although it is on the class path), as I can navigate to the urls that should be secured.

Does anyone see what's missing/wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? Obviously you can't use `@Configuration` or `@Bean` without Spring. `application.properties` is also Spring-specific, so you will not be able to use that either.

Comment: I have tried nearly everything; added Tomcat adapters, followed dozens of SO-topics, followed tutorials on adding Keycloak with Vaadin 10 and Spring, ... It seems Spring is necessary, but it seems very cumbersome to change my project to a Spring(boot) project just to add Keycloak.... Maybe somebody has experience with Vaadin 8 and Keycloak and could push me in the right direction.

Comment: Why is it cumbersome to change the project to Spring boot? It will be very difficult to get this working without. Vaadin and Keycloak have addons/adapters for Spring security that ensure correct integration.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would consider using Spring boot, I created [a working example of integration between Vaadin 8, Spring Boot and Keycloak](https://github.com/chvndb/keycloak-spring-vaadin-demo/tree/master).

It makes use of `vaadin-spring-boot`, `keycloak-spring-boot-adapter` and `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` plugins to get jump started and your `application.properties` will get picked up correctly. In essence, this setup tells Vaadin to let Spring Security handle all security, and in turn Keycloak is hooked up as the security handler.

The only configuration needed is to have a custom [SecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/chvndb/keycloak-spring-vaadin-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/demo/vaadin/config/SecurityConfiguration.java) to define your specific security needs.

But the bulk comes down to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableVaadinSharedSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    http.formLogin().disable();
    // disable spring security csrf as Vaadin already provides this
    // also possible to disable this in Vaadin and leave this enabled
    http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .logout()
        .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
        .logoutUrl("/sso/logout").permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    http
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
  }
...
}
```